# Uncaught ReferenceError: SyntaxHighlighter is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, referenceerror

A very similar question was asked on this specific error (but within a multiple-question format!) but I didn not understand the answer given (not least because I'm not a programer, I'm adjusting a BS3 template done by someone else). This mistake came with the programming, however, I would prefer to fix it if possible!

This is the header code where an error is reported:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
              <!--flexslider-->
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
              <script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                  SyntaxHighlighter.all();    // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS REPORTED
                });
                $(window).load(function(){
                  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    start: function (slider) {
                      $('body').removeClass('loading');
                    }
                  });
                });
              </script>
```

The JS files that came in the folder are the following:
- easing.js
- jquery-1.11.1.min.js
- jquery.flexslider.js
- jquery.swipebox.min.js
- modernizr.custom.js
- move-top.js

Is there anything you would recommend I fix either in the index.html file the above code is from or any of the .js files that might fix the problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334467/syntaxhighlighter-call-syntaxhighlighter-all-to-highlight-dynamically-genera

Comment: Thanks - tried the suggestion of changing .all to .highlight but it didn't work.

Comment: be sure t include the scripts for that .. http://jsfiddle.net/menelaosbgr/TXzZH/   see the External Resources on left hand side